# Delete all directories named "XXX" from sub-directories from root directory in Windows or Unix

Tags: cmd, rmdir

I have many directories with some sub-directories that need to be deleted. Is there a way to deltree/rmdir so that all directories titled "TAB", "Tab_old" and files in them are deleted.

Directory structure is like

```
root>townx>TAB
root>towny>
root>towny>TAB
root>towny>zone1>
root>towny>zone1>Tab
```

etc... so all "TAB" directories should be deleted.

===== edmastermind29 suggested process output ====

```
$ find / -name "TAB" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;

atgisuser@ATGISLAPTOP02 /c/scratch/Test_Lidar
$ ls
Ath_test.csv  LAS               Success_LOG.txt  asc
Contours      Orthophotomosaic  XYZ              schema.ini


atgisuser@ATGISLAPTOP02 /c/scratch/Test_Lidar
$ cd contours

atgisuser@ATGISLAPTOP02 /c/scratch/Test_Lidar/contours
$ ls
Atherton  TAB

atgisuser@ATGISLAPTOP02 /c/scratch/Test_Lidar/contours
$
```

The "TAB" directory above should be deleted...

Comment: So which is it? Are you on unix or DOS? Or are you actually using the Windows CMD shell?

Comment: can use commands for either system as the files are on a network and we have win7, umbuntu and cmd shell.-just put both so that I get a quick answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Windows CMD solution

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b /s /ad x:\rootFolder ^| findstr /le "\TAB \Tab_old"') do 2>nul rd /s /q "%F"
```

If used in a batch script, then `%F` must change to `%%F`

Answer (score 2):

`find / -name "XXX" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;`

`/` searches the entire file system. If you want to search just the root folder, then you would use `/root`

Usage of `-name` is case sensitive. However, `-iname` ignores case sensitivity.

In plain english, the above command states: Search the entire file system for "XXX", a directory. Upon finding "XXX", recursively remove the contents within the "XXX" directory forcefully.